# Fixing duplicate records in a rails app from an autocomplete form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building a Rails 3.1 application that allows people to submit events. One of the fields for the event is a venue. On the create/edit form, the venue_name field has autocomplete functionality so it displays venues with a similar name, but the user is able to enter any name.

When the form is submitted, I'm using find_or_create_by_name when attaching the venue to the event model.

I'm doing this because it's not possible for us to maintain a complete list of venues and I don't want to prevent people from submitting an event because the venue isn't in the list.

The problem is that it's quite likely we'll get duplicates over time like "Venue Name" and "The Venue Name" or any number of other possibilities.

I was thinking that I probably just need to create an administrative tool that allows the admin to review recent venues and if he/she thinks they're duplicates to search/select a master record and have the duplicate record's association copied over to the master record and once successful to delete the duplicate record.

Is this a good approach? In terms of the data manipulation would it be best to handle this in a transaction? Would it be best to add this functionality in a sort of utility class - or directly in the Venue model?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: i think you are on the right track. i would do it in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 0):

If I were going to put together a system like that, I'd probably try to find a unique identifier I could associate with each venue - perhaps an address or a phone number?

So, if I had "The Clubhouse" with a phone number 503-555-1212, and someone tried to input a new venue called "Clubhouse" with the phone number 503-555-1212, I might take them to an interstitial page where I ask them "Did you mean this location?"

Barring that, I might ask for a phone number or address first, then present a list of possible matches with the option to create a new venue.

Otherwise, you're introducing a lot of potential for error at the admin level, plus you run into a scalability problem. If your admin has to review 10 entries a month, maybe not so bad -  but if your app takes off and that number goes to 1000, that becomes unmanageable fast!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Right now, I'm only asking for the venue name - no other data at the event level. This is mostly because I expect they should find the venue they're looking for in most cases. The scaleability problem is reduced for this app because the events are all in one medium-sized city. I could add a check though if they enter a new venue rather than selecting one from autosuggest to enter a phone number and do a check from that. That could certainly reduce the problem, but I doubt it would eliminate it completely.

Comment: I see where you're coming from, certainly. I think I'd still argue in favor of adding some sort of event-level check, though, as a safeguard against user "creativity". :) Any time you have key data driven by user input, it's worth jumping through a hoop or two to get everything as much into its groove as you can.  At the end of the day, I think there are only two solutions here: restrict the input on the way in, or resolve to fix it afterward. After-the-fact administrative cleanup, while it might be necessary for edge cases, should probably not be part of your everyday operational flow.